# add image for dropdown in blockly

Tags: blockly, google-blockly

I am developing blockly and I need a dropdown which use image instead of text. My code is like this.

```
Blockly.Blocks['image_dropdown_test']={
    init: function(){
        var options = [
            [{'src': 'canada.svg', 'width': 50, 'height': 25, 'alt': 'Canada'}, 'CANADA']
            ]
        this.appendValueInput("fl").appendField("adsad").appendField(new Blockly.FieldDropdown(options), 'FLAG');
        this.setTooltip('');
        this.setHelpUrl('');
    }
};
```

I cannot define it successfully and I got a `Uncaught TypeError: text.replace is not a function` error. Anyone can help me ?

Comment: I just copied your code into the playground and imported this XML:

    `<xml xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      <block type="image_dropdown_test"></block>
    </xml>`

It worked fine except that the image (canada.svg) was not defined, so it fell back on the alt text.  I replaced it with an image that I know exists: `../media/test_a.png` and it rendered fine.

Comment: Hrm... I checked this out in the Blockly playground here (https://blockly-demo.appspot.com/static/tests/playground.html) and it loaded, yet when I tried it in our own (outdated) Blockly environment, I replicated your issue. I assume the documentation references the most recent version, and I know our environment is a fork of a fairly old version. Are you by chance using a fork of an older Blockly version?